# ¿Asignar una condicion IS NOT NULL a una Variable?

Tags: sql, sql-server

Amigos tengo una consulta de la siguiente manera

```
WHERE 
     bt.ProductoID= CASE WHEN @ProductoID IS NOT NULL THEN @ProductoID ELSE IS NOT NULL END
  AND (bt.talla= @talla AND bt.Año =@Año)
```

El problema que tengo es que es tengo que hacer una un procedimiento de busqueda el usuario puede enviar uno o hasta 5 parametros para filtrar la busqueda, mi idea es que cuando un filtro este como nulo no sea tomado en cuenta, como se daran cuenta estoy utilizando en "CASE" como operador ternario pero el problema que tengo es que el "IS NOT NULL" no se lo puedo asignar, si alguien me pudiera ayudar o decirme como puedo hacer la busqueda.

Comment: Por que no le asignas null??

Comment: en caso de que el parametro @ProductoID vaya vacio quiero hacer algo como lo siguiente bt.ProductoID = IS NOT NULL pero es donde me marca el erros.

Answer (score 2):

Si buscas no usar el filtro cuando `@ProductoID` sea `NULL` ( o cualquier otro de los parámetros)  puedes hacer lo siguiente:

```
WHERE ( @ProductoID IS NULL OR bt.ProductoID = @ProductoID )
      AND (@Año IS NULL OR bt.Año = @Año)
      -- y así con cada uno de los filtros
```

Esta forma es muy útil para armar una consulta muy flexible, pero tiene un eventual problema, que es producto de algo que se denomina [**Parameter sniffing**](https://www.sqlshack.com/sql-server-2016-parameter-sniffing/), de forma resumida: el motor optimizará un SP considerando la cardinalidad de los parámetros con los que se lo invoca, y como solo existe una sola optimización para el SP, podría ocurrir que ésta funcione bien para una combinación particular de filtros pero para otra todo lo contrario. Esto es muy habitual de ver cuando un SP, invocado con un conjunto de parámetros, recupera un gran cantidad de registros y con otra combinación solo uno, en alguna de las dos formas tendrás seguramente una penalidad en la performance.

Answer (score 1):

En este caso a mi forma de pensar, puedes hacer lo siguiente:

```
WHERE bt.ProductoID = ISNULL(@ProductoID,bt.ProductoID)
AND bt.Talla=ISNULL(@Talla,bt.Talla)
AND bt.Año=ISNULL(@Año,bt.Año)
```

Como es que funciona? Lo que hace ISNULL es que si el parámetro de Busqueda no es nulo, restringe la busqueda a lo que coincida con ese parametro, pero si dicho parametro llega como nulo entonces toma todo lo que existe en bt.Año.

Ahora bien hay una excepción con el manejo de valores nulos, en Sql server no puedes comparar si Null = Null entonces debes utilizar un doble ISNULL asignandole un valor si es nulo, y lo mismo del lado derecho, por ejemplo un 0 para que haga un 0 = 0 quedando de la siguiente manera.

```
 WHERE ISNULL(bt.ProductoID,0) = ISNULL(@ProductoID,ISNULL(bt.ProductoID,0))
 AND ISNULL(bt.Talla,0)=ISNULL(@Talla,ISNULL(bt.Talla,0))
 AND ISNULL(bt.Año,0)=ISNULL(@Año,ISNULL(bt.Año,0))
```

Agregado a esto, te recomiendo que si estas trabajando con parámetros y variables, identifiques con @P los parametros y @V las variables, esto por buenas prácticas.

```
@PParametro
@VVariable
```

Y un pequeño ejemplo práctico:

```
DECLARE @PDescripcion VARCHAR(30)=NULL, 
        @PId INT

DECLARE @VDescripcion AS VARCHAR(30)='Descripcion1'

DECLARE @Tabla AS TABLE(
    ID INT,
    Descripcion VARCHAR(30)
)

INSERT INTO @Tabla
SELECT 1, 'Descripcion1'

INSERT INTO @Tabla
SELECT 2, 'Descripcion2'

INSERT INTO @Tabla
SELECT NULL, 'Descripcion3'


--Utilizando el parametro
SELECT *
FROM @Tabla
WHERE Descripcion = ISNULL(@PDescripcion,Descripcion)   --Si el parametro descripcion es nulo entonces toma todo el contenido en Descripcion

--Utilizando la variable
SELECT *
FROM @Tabla
WHERE Descripcion = ISNULL(@VDescripcion,Descripcion) --Como la variable no es nula busca las coincidencias con la variable

--Comparando valores nulos
SELECT *
FROM @Tabla
WHERE ID = ISNULL(@PDescripcion,ID) --No podras ver el valor nulo por no poder comparar null con null

SELECT *
FROM @Tabla
WHERE ISNULL(ID,0) = ISNULL(@PDescripcion,ISNULL(ID,0))-- Puedes ver el registro null ya que comparas en lugar de null = null con 0 = 0
```

Espero sea de ayuda mi respuesta.

Comment: Me sirvio mucho el ISNULL, lo que habia hecho es lo siguiente:

```WHERE  (bt.ProductoID = CASE WHEN @ProductoID IS NOT NULL THEN @ProductoID ELSE bt.ProductoID END)```
Me parece que funcionaria igual o me equivoco ?

Comment: Si funcionaría igual, solo que cuando utilizo el Case de esa forma he visto que baja el rendimiento de la consulta.